# how to write a single function for getting different time zones in php?

Tags: php, date, time

I am creating a script that allows the user to choose their own timezone...
and enter the date $ time..So the user entered date/time must be converted to GMT format while storing into the database.
While retrieving from the database it should be again converted into original format.
Here DST concept must also be included.

So here date can be  in a variable which can be a string or array(multidimensional array also)
So i tried like this.....

```
function ConvertOneTimezoneToAnotherTimezone($time,$currentTimezone,$timezoneRequired)
{

    $current_zone = new DateTimeZone($currentTimezone);
    //$gmt = new DateTimeZone('GMT');

    $date = new DateTime($time, $current_zone);
    //$date->setTimezone($gmt);
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezoneRequired));

    return  $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

 // Convert it back to Original timezone
     $date->setTimezone($current_zone);
     return  $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 }

 $time='2011-03-29 11:15:00.000';

 echo  "Current Date/Time is=".ConvertOneTimezoneToAnotherTimezone($time,'Asia/Kolkata','America/New_York');
```

but here i am only able to convert into different timezones,but i want a single function which converts date/time and also while retrieving gives original format......
please anybody help me......

Comment: Can you provide your expected output? You are returning from the function after your first setTimeZone, so you will never reach the second one. Are you saying you'd like to retrieve the values from both $date->format() calls?

Comment: ya i want output as converted date/time=2011-12-28 07:22:00
original date/time2011-12-28 17:52:00.and this date can be in an array or it can also be a string.

Answer (score 0):

something like this
http://service-kl.com/code/tz_demo2/?cou=USA

Comment: That link is dead which is why answers that only contain links [are considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: thanks, I put correct link... btw, considered bad practice by who?

Comment: There is a link embedded in my comment.  Here's the link again http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function ConvertOneTimezoneToAnotherTimezone($originalDateTime, $originalTimeZone, $targetTimeZone) {
    $format   = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

    $dateTime = new DateTime($originalDateTime, new DateTimeZone($originalTimeZone));
    $original = $dateTime->format($format);

    $dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($targetTimeZone));
    $target   = $dateTime->format($format);

    return compact('original', 'target');
}

$dateTime  = '2011-03-29 11:15:00.000';
$converted = ConvertOneTimezoneToAnotherTimezone($dateTime,'Asia/Kolkata','America/New_York');

echo sprintf('Original  Date/Time is=%s', $converted['original']), PHP_EOL;
echo sprintf('Converted Date/Time is=%s', $converted['target']), PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: ok thankx wilmoore.your code works fine........but inside the function only i need to check for the condition where date can be an array value or it can also be a string,according only i need to display both the dates.